# RSA key pair generation in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, rsa

I'm trying to generate RSA-2048 key pair in ActionScript. The library I'm using is flame crypto library.

It takes more than 60 seconds, so it exceeds maximum script execution time and halts.
So I compiled C math library (libtommath) into SWC using Crossbridge and called its prime number generation function. But it still takes more than 40 seconds.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this need to run in Flash Player or is AIR an option too ? If AIR is an option you can probably use a process running in the background that will generate the key. For Flash Player, you can try to use actionscript workers/threads and see if that will help. Alternatively, see if you can use a server side language (e.g. [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php)) to generate the key and read the result in ActionScript

Comment: libtommath is quite fast, so if you compiled it with all optimisations, don't expect to improve much on that aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSA key generation is *a dog*. It's probably the most demanding algorithm you'll ever encounter. It requires a lot of random data, and the prime tests are dog slow as well. Furthermore, RSA key pair generation time is rather *indeterministic*; it may find a prime fast or it may not. It doesn't help that scripting languages are not that good in performing these kind of low level functions.

There are two things you could do:

1. break out to OpenSSL, OpenSSL is one of the fastest libraries out there;
2. create the key pair in a secure environment and copy it *securely* into the ActionScript environment.

That last option seems strange, as you may want the user to generate the key pair instead. But ask yourself this question: how can you trust the public key generated by ActionScript?